# jQuery replace text not working

Tags: jquery, replace

I am using this method to find and replace a piece of text and not sure why it is not working? When I use console.log, I can see the correct content I want to replace but the end result is not working:

```
(function($) {
  $(document).ready( function() {
        var theContent = $(".transaction-results p").last();
        console.log(theContent.html());
        theContent.html().replace(/Total:/, 'Total without shipping:');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Any thoughts?

Thank you!

Comment: string.replace returns a string - it doesn't do the replace on the string you reference... `theContent.html(theContent.html().replace(/Total:/, 'Total without shipping:'));`

Comment: @diEcho This isn't PHP, you don't wrap regex in quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have extra `:` in string to search and also assign it back to html of theContent

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/T8Lce/1/)**

```
  $(document).ready( function() {
        var theContent = $(".transaction-results p").last();
        console.log(theContent.html());
        theContent.html(theContent.html().replace(/Total/, 'Total without shipping:'));
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

The string was replaced, but you didn't reassign the string to the html of the element. Use `return`:

```
theContent.html(function(i,h){
    return h.replace(/Total:/, 'Total without shipping:');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pyxhq/1/) (kindly contributed by [diEcho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155861/diecho)).

References:

- [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

Answer (score 0):

```
(function($) {
  $(document).ready( function() {
        var theContent = $(".transaction-results p").last();
        console.log(theContent.html());
        theContent.html(theContent.html().replace('Total:', 'Total without shipping:'));
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Why you did `/Total:/` and not `'Total'` like a normal string?

-The solution from @David Thomas works.

Comment: Because he was using regular expressions, not strings.